# add class to table cell onClick angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have certain number of rows and columns  and I want to add class ('xyz') to table cell  onClick and it should not loose that class when i click on other cell...please help...

```
<table class="table-bordered select-table">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in letterArray" ng-init="rowIndex = $index">
       <td class="lettersoup" ng-id="{{$parent.$index+''+$index}}" ng-repeat="column in row  track by $index" ng-class="" ng-mouseup="removeFlag()" ng-mousedown="setFlag($parent.$index,$index);" ng-mousemove="drawImage($parent.$index,$index)">{{column}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: please don't abandon a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33450464/highlight-all-the-cell-from-which-my-mouse-is-passing-the-highlight-should-not) and then ask the same question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question is from last year, but hopefully this will help someone out there.

Here's what I used to set an "active" class on a selected table row. This works because each ng-repeat iteration has it's own scope. My search results were an array of objects.

ng-click dynamically adds a new "Selected" property to the current result object. ng-class executes in the same scope as the current ng-repeat iteration so it can reference the local variable "result". ng-class toggles the "active" class if the current search result's "Selected" property is true.

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in SearchResults"
    ng-class="{'active': result.Selected}"
    ng-click="result.Selected = true; SearchResultSelected(result)"
    ng-cloak>
    <td>{{result.Status}}</td>
    <td>{{result.ID}}</td>
    <td>{{result.Phone}}</td>
    <td>{{result.Name}}</td>
    <td>{{result.AddressLine1}}</td>
    <td>{{result.AddressLine2}}</td>
    <td>{{result.CityName}}</td>
    <td>{{result.StateName}}</td>
    <td>{{result.ZipCode}}</td>
    <td>{{result.Environment}}</td>
</tr>
```

So if you could change your "column" variable to an object, you could leverage my method of achieving this.

I'm guessing your data structure looks like this: ['A', 'B', ...]

I would recommend doing this: [{Letter: 'A'}, {Letter: 'B'}, ...]

That way you can do this:

```
<table class="table-bordered select-table">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in letterArray" ng-init="rowIndex = $index">
       <td class="lettersoup" 
           ng-id="{{$parent.$index+''+$index}}" 
           ng-repeat="column in row  track by $index" 
           ng-class="{'xyz': column.Selected}"
           ng-click="column.Selected = true; doSomeOtherActionOrCallFunction()"
           ng-mouseup="removeFlag()" 
           ng-mousedown="setFlag($parent.$index,$index);" 
           ng-mousemove="drawImage($parent.$index,$index)">{{column.Letter}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is to add a class (meaning you don't want to trigger another digest loop) I would suggest to go with old plain `onclick="this.className += '  xyz'"`, rather then `ngClick`:

```
<table class="table-bordered select-table">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in letterArray" ng-init="rowIndex = $index">
       <td class="lettersoup" 
           onclick="this.className += ' xyz'"
           ng-id="{{$parent.$index+''+$index}}" 
           ng-repeat="column in row  track by $index" 
           ng-mouseup="removeFlag()" ng-mousedown="setFlag($parent.$index,$index);" 
           ng-mousemove="drawImage($parent.$index,$index)">{{column}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What you are describing in this comment contradicts your question.

Comment: ok i simple language..when the user Click the table cell it should highlight the particular cell using angularjs...but then i should be able to highlight the other cell without removing the previous highlighted cell

Comment: What I posted does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object and store the positions as keys. Also, I'm not sure if you want the click to be a toggle or just want it to always add the class to the cell. If the last behavior is what you want, this code should do the trick.

```
<table class="table-bordered select-table" ng-init="clickedCells = {}">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in letterArray" ng-init="rowIndex = $index">
        <td class="lettersoup" ng-class="{ xyz: clickedCells[$parent.$index + ':' + $index] }" ng-mouseenter="clickedCells[$parent.$index + ':' + $index] = true" ng-id="{{$parent.$index + '' + $index}}" ng-repeat="column in row  track by $index" ng-class="" ng-mouseup="removeFlag()" ng-mousedown="setFlag($parent.$index,$index);" ng-mousemove="drawImage($parent.$index,$index)">{{column}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However you should abstract the code of the ng-mouseenter into a function in your controller, and call the function in the view.

Comment: actually i want to highlight  the table cell on onmouseover...and i want to highlight all the cell from which my mouse is passing...the highlight should not be removed when mouse go from one cell to another

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain myself correctly. What I meant by "highlighting" was actually adding/remove the class xyz.

Comment: Ok, so you want to add the class when the mouse hovers, and you want the class to remain there even when it exists, correct?

Comment: Ok, updated my answer. Basically, you just have to change ng-click for ng-mouseenter.

Comment: and what about controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93868/discussion-between-pedro-m-silva-and-shank).